# How to resolve all implementations of one interface in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-container

Okay, I want to create arbitrary implementations of a specific Interface and resolve them. It's actually similiar to a plugin system. "Create your own Implementation of intereface X  and the app does the rest"

```
public interface IMenuEntry { ... }

// auto-mapping (registration-by-convention)
_container.RegisterTypes(AllClasses.FromAssemblies(assemblies), 
                         WithMappings.FromMatchingInterface, 
                         // ResolveAll need names for multiple registrations of the same type (?)
                         WithName.TypeName,                 
                         WithLifetime.ContainerControlled);

var g = _container.ResolveAll<IMenuEntry>(); // empty - why?
```

When I check my container registrations my implemantations are there and the name is the name of the *class* - not the interface. Wonderful. **But why can't I resolve all implementations of `IMenuEntry`?** It is always empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`WithMappings.FromMatchingInterface` will only match a type named `MenuEntry` to `IMenuEntry`.

You might try `WithMappings.FromAllInterfaces` instead.

See the [WithMappings methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/dn169696(v=pandp.31)) documentation.

Comment: Ohhh... Well these are the drawbacks when you glance over a documentation.. Solved my problem. Thank you!